# A service to generate examples of context of a word?

Tags: nlp

I want to type in "car" and get:

One day, I came to a car and bought it.
Teacher told us that cars are pricey.
etc. etc. etc..

Basically just sentences where the word is used.

Opensource and german preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The Leipzig Wortschatz project offers such services on their Web interface, try http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/

You can also download their corpora.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktionary has ever-improving example sentences and open source tools for programmatically using such data.

Note also that Google Translate does this, but it is not offered in the official API.